# Appium error : appium-python script cannot connect to the app, whereas Appium Desktop does

Tags: python, appium, python-appium

I am trying to automate some tasks on an android emulator, and faces a very strange problem : my Appium + Python script cannot even launch the application, whereas everything works fine with Appium Desktop.

Here are the details :

First, I launch my avd (with a first script):

```
date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")
try:
    emu_process = subprocess.run("adb kill-server")
    print(emu_process)
except Exception as e:
    print("exception : {}".format(e))
    pass
emu_process = subprocess.Popen(["{}\emulator\emulator.exe".format(os.getenv('ANDROID_SDK_ROOT')),
                                "-avd", "{}".format(emu_model)])
emu_process = subprocess.run("adb start-server")

# Wait until the device is connected
time.sleep(2)
ready = False
while not ready:
    emu_process = subprocess.run("adb devices",
                                 capture_output=True, text=True)
    print(emu_process.stdout)
    print(emu_process.stdout[:4] == "List")


    if emu_process.stdout[:4] == "List" and \
            emu_process.stdout[-8:-2] == "device":
        ready=True
    time.sleep(2)

# store logcat on a .txt file
emu_process = subprocess.Popen(["adb", "logcat", "*:I", ">", 
                                "{}_adb.log".format(date)], shell=True)
```

Then, if I launch Appium Desktop on localhost, port 4723 with the desired capabilities :

```
{
  "platformName": "Android",
  "platformVersion": "10",
  "deviceName": "Android Emulator",
  "appPackage": "com.google.android.calculator",
  "appActivity": "com.android.calculator2.Calculator"
}
```

The google calculator is launched.

BUT, if I launch the Following script, the script is stuck in the webdriver.remote line :

```
from appium import webdriver
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime
from appium.webdriver.appium_service import AppiumService

# kill current node instance, to avoid multiple appium session
subprocess.Popen(['taskkill', '/F', '/IM', 'node.exe'])

ip_address = '127.0.0.1'
port = '4723'
date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")

# Run Appium server, store logfile
appium_service = AppiumService()
appium_service.start(args=['--address', ip_address, '-p', port,
                           '--log-timestamp', '--log', 'D:\Temp\{}_appium.log'.format(date)])

print("appium is running : ", appium_service.is_running) # return True, ok
print("appium is listening : ", appium_service.is_listening) # return True, ok

desired_caps = {"platformName": "Android",
                "platformVersion": "10",
                "deviceName": "Android Emulator",
                "appPackage": "com.google.android.calculator",
                "appActivity": "com.android.calculator2.Calculator"
                }


driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://{}:{}/wd/hub'.format(ip_address, port),
    desired_capabilities=desired_caps
)

print("appium is connected to the device") # Nothing is printed, the script is stuck in the webdriver.remote line
```

Could you please help me to make this script running ? I have already tried a lot of things, during a week or so, and I have no idea what is going wrong.

Thank you for any help,

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have the answer.
I seems to be a bug, referenced here :
https://github.com/appium/python-client/issues/534

The workaround is to write

```
appium_service.start(args=..., stdout=sp.DEVNULL)
```

instead of :

```
appium_service.start(args=...)
```

Hope others will be happy as I am to find this answer :)